# PHP - how to use a 'break;' in a ternary operator

Tags: php, foreach, logic, ternary-operator

I have the following function. It compares one value to each value in an array.

```
function catExists($id) {
    $cats = getCats();
    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
        if ($cat['id'] == $id) {
            return true;break;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to shorten the whole thing by using ternary operators.

```
function catExists($id) {
    foreach (getCats() as $cat) return ($cat['id'] == $id) ? true : false;
}
```

The problem I have is that I can't use `break;` when the condition turns to `true`. i.e The returned value will keep reverting back to `false` unless the `true` condition is at the end of the `array`.

Is their a way that this can be achieved on a single line?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is an overkill. That is not what ternary operations are meant to do.

Comment: the break is utterly pointless. the `return` will terminate the function, making the `break` unreachable code. And since you have a `return` in BOTH branches of your `if()`, your loop can only ever do ONE iteration.

Comment: Karth, no disputing that this is overkill :-). Thanks Mark, I wasn't aware of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not what ternary operators are meant to do. Keep it simple (KISS). You don't need the break statement at all since `return` ends the function execution and returns the program control back to the main program.

I'd write it this way:

```
function catExists($id) {
    foreach (getCats() as $cat) {
        if ($cat['id'] == $id)
            return true;          
    }
    return false; // 'return true' never happened, so return false
}
```

If you really want to make it one line, you could use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/array_column) in conjunction with [`array_search()`](http://php.net/array_search) like so:

```
function catExists($id) {
    return array_search($id, array_column(getCats(), 'id')) !== FALSE;
}
```

Comment: I agree. It is overkill, but my brain is just about to implode from the clutter. Going minimal seams like a nice alternative. Anyhow, thank you very much :-)